# Database architecture for chatting app to handle tons of users

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I found all applications has Messages Collection but I found it insufficient to search all web-app messages every time you get a request.
So If I thought about making a collection for each person is this a good practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that would mean a couple of things:

1. If you had 100 users, you would have 100 collections. Afterwards, if you get 1000 users , you would have to create an additional 900 collections. That is not practical as you would have to keep creating new collections as the number of users increases.
2. You would have to somehow keep track of the collection relatively to the user. Most DBs have nothing like that out of the box and you would have to create from scratch a program just to be able to delete update etc the correct collections. This is not a small task. Your time is better put to use developing the main functionality of your app
3. DBs specialize in data lookup in collections, as long as you have your collection properly indexed , you could put millions of messages in a collection and find the ones you need in almost no time at all.

And that is just the tip of the iceberg. As such, making collections per user are not only bad practice , but very impractical unfortunately.

Having said all that, I encourage to keep thinking out of the box. Not all the ideas will work out (like this one), but many great innovations have come from trying something new.